# How can use Microsoft Oslo Library for solve stiff equations?

Tags: c#, ode, differential-equations, equation-solving

which phrase in Microsoft Oslo Library can solve the Stiff ordinary differential Equations?
is there another way to solve them at all?

Answer (score 0):

Any method that invites you to provide the Jacobian is an implicit method and thus (better) suited for stiff equations. Here that is the BDF method.